# LINQ to SQL - Multiple Anonymous Columns

Tags: sql, visual-studio, linq, stored-procedures

I am trying to update my DBML file for a stored procedure and it is returning an error that I have never seen before and tried to find a reputable resource for solving and have been unable to at this point. The error is:

> Unsupported Stored Procedure Unable to extract stored procedure
>   'procedurename' because its result set contains multiple anonymous
>   columns.

I have loaded this stored procedure into the DBML successfully numerous times. What might be causing the issue all of the sudden? Thanks!

Here is what the auto-generated data-class code used to look like (restored from a backup). I hope it helps decipher what is going on.

```
        [global::System.Data.Linq.Mapping.FunctionAttribute(Name="dbo.parseXMLForK12_EachStudent")]
    public ISingleResult<parseXMLForK12_EachStudentResult> parseXMLForK12_EachStudent([global::System.Data.Linq.Mapping.ParameterAttribute(DbType="NVarChar(MAX)")] string strXML, [global::System.Data.Linq.Mapping.ParameterAttribute(DbType="Date")] System.Nullable<System.DateTime> datesaved, [global::System.Data.Linq.Mapping.ParameterAttribute(DbType="Int")] System.Nullable<int> filepassed, [global::System.Data.Linq.Mapping.ParameterAttribute(DbType="Int")] System.Nullable<int> whichproc)
    {
        IExecuteResult result = this.ExecuteMethodCall(this, ((MethodInfo)(MethodInfo.GetCurrentMethod())), strXML, datesaved, filepassed, whichproc);
        return ((ISingleResult<parseXMLForK12_EachStudentResult>)(result.ReturnValue));
    }



public partial class parseXMLForK12_EachStudentResult
{

    private System.Nullable<int> _Column1;

    public parseXMLForK12_EachStudentResult()
    {
    }

    [global::System.Data.Linq.Mapping.ColumnAttribute(Name="", Storage="_Column1", DbType="Int")]
    public System.Nullable<int> Column1
    {
        get
        {
            return this._Column1;
        }
        set
        {
            if ((this._Column1 != value))
            {
                this._Column1 = value;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Add an [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) to your question.

Comment: could it be, multiple anonymous columns suggest that the result set from your stored procedure is returning data without column names?

Comment: Matt - To your point I went back and added column alias names to the select statements and refreshed the dbml and it shows the updated names but still runs into the same error. I would post the stored procedure but it contains sensitive business logic.

Comment: What would cause this issue out of the blue? The select statements have been in use for over a year with the same logic and when reimporting these to the DBML file I run into this issue.

Comment: Please see my updated question for the dataclass code the LINQ to SQL built previously to it breaking.